# Java - Issues with Netbeans calculator clear button

Tags: java

I just started programming and I've stumbled on some problems.

I made a simple calculator in Netbeans IDE.

The first time i run the calculator and i for example enter: 100/5=20
Then i click my "clear button" and the when i enter: 100/5= 0

However the weird part is that sometimes when i re-run the calculator it works after i use my clear button. Sometimes it does not.

I'm guessing there are some bugs happening? Would appreciate all the help I can get!

```
  private void numberButtonClicked(String numberClicked) {
            String input = txtInputfield.getText();
        
      
        if(txtInputfield.getText().isEmpty()&&operator==null)
            txtInputfield.setText(numberClicked);
        
         
        else if (operator!=null)
        {
           .
            txtInputfield.setText(txtInputfield.getText() + numberClicked);
            
            value2 = Integer.parseInt(value2 + numberClicked);
            
        }
       
        else
            txtInputfield.setText(txtInputfield.getText()+ numberClicked);
    }
    private void btn1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
      numberButtonClicked("1");
      
    }                                 

    private void btn2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        
     numberButtonClicked("2");
     
    }                                 

    private void btn3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
      numberButtonClicked("3");
     
    }                                 

    private void btn4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("4");
       
    }                                 

    private void btn5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("5");
       
    }                                 

    private void btn6MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        numberButtonClicked("6");
        
    }                                 

    private void btn7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("7");
       
    }                                 

    private void btn8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("8");
       
    }                                 

    private void btn9MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("9");
       
    }                                 

    private void btn0MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       numberButtonClicked("0");
       
    }                                 

    private void btnClearMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
      
        value2 = 0;
        txtInputfield.setText("");
        value1 = 0;
        txtInputfield.setText("");
    }                                     

    private void operatorClicked(String operatorName, String operatorSymbol){
          if(txtInputfield.getText().isEmpty())
           return;
       .
        if (operator!=null&&value2!=0) {
            double answer = 0;
           if (operator=="plus")
               answer = value1 + value2;
           else if (operator=="minus")
               answer = value1 - value2;
           else if (operator=="multiplication")
               answer = value1 * value2;
           else if (operator=="division")
               answer = value1/value2;
           
           
           value1=(int)answer;
           
           value2 = 0;
           
           txtInputfield.setText("");
           
          
           operator = operatorName;
           
        } else {
            value1 = Integer.parseInt(txtInputfield.getText());
            txtInputfield.setText(txtInputfield.getText() + " " + operatorSymbol + " ");
            operator = operatorName;
        }
        
        
    }
    private void btnPlusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
      operatorClicked("plus","+");
         
    }                                    

    private void btnMinusMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
       operatorClicked("minus","-");
       
    }                                     

    private void btnDivisionMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        
       operatorClicked("division", "/");
       
    }                                        

    private void btnMultiplicationMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
       operatorClicked("multiplication", "*");
       
    }                                              

    private void btnEqualMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        
        double answer = 0;
        if (operator=="plus")
            answer = value1 + value2;
        else if (operator=="minus")
            answer = value1 - value2;
        else if (operator=="multiplication")
            answer = value1 * value2;
        else if (operator=="division")
            answer = value1 / value2;
        
        String input = Double.toString(answer);
        txtInputfield.setText(input);
    }
```

Comment: What is the period in the middle of the code?

Comment: There is some weird stuff with `operator` vs `operatorName` vs `operatorSymbol`.  And you should not use `==` to test of strings are equal.